# How can I make 2 windows installations appear in the grub menu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, grub2

I have installed Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu, and I have the following problem:

Grub2 only recognizes one version, the Windows 8 bootloader (which is located on a hidden partition called System).
Apparently, the Windows 8 bootloader chain loads windows 7 (even though the default OS is set to windows 7). So instead of booting windows 7 directly from Grub, it goes through grub > windows 8 > windows 7. And also, I need to go through 2 different boot menus in order to boot either windows version, which is very inefficient.

How can I add both Windows 7 and Windows 8 to the grub2 menu?

Answer (score 1):

If Grub2 shows one of them, it'll be pretty easy if you know your hard drive set-up.

You can check the current grub.cfg file at /boot/grub/grub.cfg (but do not edit this one, it's built from the options in /etc/grub.d/*)

Take special note of the Windows entry, which should be there.  It should look similar to this (pulled from grub2 on gentoo):

> menuentry "Microsoft Windows (version)" {
>       insmod chain
>       set root=(hd1,1)
>       drivemap -s hd0 hd1
>       chainloader +1
>   }

So figure out where the root of your W7 and W8 are relative to your grub disc (hd0) and add custom lines in /etc/grub.d/40_custom that resemble the above with your custom info in it.  Assuming that the current 8 loader for you is correct, 7 should be pretty easy to set up.

After you get that, you need to update the grub.cfg with:

> sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to add it to grub but I suggest you try out [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). I had a Windows 7, Windows 8 CP, Ubuntu set up and for the same reason as you have described, I used EasyBCD instead of using Grub. So, give it a try! And yes, they do have adequate documentation on how to configure and set it up too.